# Unstacking data.frame obtained via BDH function in Rbbg package

Tags: r, date, reshape

I have attempted numerous methods to unstack historical data using Rbbg package. I have a column of 150 tickers, each within the date range of 1-1-2010 to 6-30-2015.

I have tried using the example from the Rbbg manual:

```
t <- unstack(na.omit(FI_data), PX_LAST~ticker)
rownames(t) <- unique(na.omit(FI_data)$date)
t
```

When I run the second line above I receieve the following error:

Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-08", "2010-01-15",  :  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions

I have also tried:

```
z <- read.zoo(FI_data, index.column = 'date', split = "PX_LAST")
```

and get the following error:

Error in merge.zoo(`-0.293` = c("GTCHF10Y Corp", "GTCHF10Y Corp"), `-0.179` = c("GTCHF10Y Corp",  : 
  series cannot be merged with non-unique index entries in a series
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Sample:

> dput(subset(FI_data[200:400,]))
>   structure(list(ticker = c("LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", "LBUSOAS Index", 
>   "LBUSOAS Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index", 
>   "LUCRTREU Index", "LUCRTREU Index"), date = c("2013-10-25", "2013-11-01", 
>   "2013-11-08", "2013-11-15", "2013-11-22", "2013-11-29", "2013-12-06", 
>   "2013-12-13", "2013-12-20", "2013-12-27", "2014-01-03", "2014-01-10", 
>   "2014-01-17", "2014-01-24", "2014-01-31", "2014-02-07", "2014-02-14", 
>   "2014-02-21", "2014-02-28", "2014-03-07", "2014-03-14", "2014-03-21", 
>   "2014-03-28", "2014-04-04", "2014-04-11", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-25", 
>   "2014-05-02", "2014-05-09", "2014-05-16", "2014-05-23", "2014-05-30", 
>   "2014-06-06", "2014-06-13", "2014-06-20", "2014-06-27", "2014-07-04", 
>   "2014-07-11", "2014-07-18", "2014-07-25", "2014-08-01", "2014-08-08", 
>   "2014-08-15", "2014-08-22", "2014-08-29", "2014-09-05", "2014-09-12", 
>   "2014-09-19", "2014-09-26", "2014-10-03", "2014-10-10", "2014-10-17", 
>   "2014-10-24", "2014-10-31", "2014-11-07", "2014-11-14", "2014-11-21", 
>   "2014-11-28", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-12", "2014-12-19", "2014-12-26", 
>   "2015-01-02", "2015-01-09", "2015-01-16", "2015-01-23", "2015-01-30", 
>   "2015-02-06", "2015-02-13", "2015-02-20", "2015-02-27", "2015-03-06", 
>   "2015-03-13", "2015-03-20", "2015-03-27", "2015-04-03", "2015-04-10", 
>   "2015-04-17", "2015-04-24", "2015-05-01", "2015-05-08", "2015-05-15", 
>   "2015-05-22", "2015-05-29", "2015-06-05", "2015-06-12", "2015-06-19", 
>   "2015-06-26", "2015-07-03", "2015-07-10", "2015-07-17", "2015-07-24", 
>   "2010-01-01", "2010-01-08", "2010-01-15", "2010-01-22", "2010-01-29", 
>   "2010-02-05", "2010-02-12", "2010-02-19", "2010-02-26", "2010-03-05", 
>   "2010-03-12", "2010-03-19", "2010-03-26", "2010-04-02", "2010-04-09", 
>   "2010-04-16", "2010-04-23", "2010-04-30", "2010-05-07", "2010-05-14", 
>   "2010-05-21", "2010-05-28", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-11", "2010-06-18", 
>   "2010-06-25", "2010-07-02", "2010-07-09", "2010-07-16", "2010-07-23", 
>   "2010-07-30", "2010-08-06", "2010-08-13", "2010-08-20", "2010-08-27", 
>   "2010-09-03", "2010-09-10", "2010-09-17", "2010-09-24", "2010-10-01", 
>   "2010-10-08", "2010-10-15", "2010-10-22", "2010-10-29", "2010-11-05", 
>   "2010-11-12", "2010-11-19", "2010-11-26", "2010-12-03", "2010-12-10", 
>   "2010-12-17", "2010-12-24", "2010-12-31", "2011-01-07", "2011-01-14", 
>   "2011-01-21", "2011-01-28", "2011-02-04", "2011-02-11", "2011-02-18", 
>   "2011-02-25", "2011-03-04", "2011-03-11", "2011-03-18", "2011-03-25", 
>   "2011-04-01", "2011-04-08", "2011-04-15", "2011-04-22", "2011-04-29", 
>   "2011-05-06", "2011-05-13", "2011-05-20", "2011-05-27", "2011-06-03", 
>   "2011-06-10", "2011-06-17", "2011-06-24", "2011-07-01", "2011-07-08", 
>   "2011-07-15", "2011-07-22", "2011-07-29", "2011-08-05", "2011-08-12", 
>   "2011-08-19", "2011-08-26", "2011-09-02", "2011-09-09", "2011-09-16", 
>   "2011-09-23", "2011-09-30", "2011-10-07", "2011-10-14", "2011-10-21", 
>   "2011-10-28", "2011-11-04", "2011-11-11", "2011-11-18", "2011-11-25", 
>   "2011-12-02", "2011-12-09", "2011-12-16", "2011-12-23", "2011-12-30", 
>   "2012-01-06", "2012-01-13", "2012-01-20", "2012-01-27"), PX_LAST = c(0.5, 
>   0.51, 0.51, 0.49, 0.48, 0.5, 0.48, 0.47, 0.46, 0.45, 0.44, 0.44, 
>   0.44, 0.45, 0.47, 0.45, 0.45, 0.44, 0.44, 0.43, 0.46, 0.43, 0.44, 
>   0.42, 0.43, 0.42, 0.41, 0.41, 0.4, 0.42, 0.4, 0.4, 0.38, 0.39, 
>   0.36, 0.38, 0.37, 0.39, 0.4, 0.4, 0.41, 0.43, 0.43, 0.42, 0.42, 
>   0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.45, 0.46, 0.44, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 
>   0.45, 0.46, 0.46, 0.49, 0.47, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5, 0.54, 0.5, 0.51, 
>   0.47, 0.45, 0.43, 0.43, 0.42, 0.45, 0.46, 0.46, 0.47, 0.44, 0.45, 
>   0.44, 0.44, 0.43, 0.44, 0.44, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5, 0.51, 
>   0.52, 0.53, 0.55, 132.82, 134.09, 134.52, 136.99, 139.23, 141.56, 
>   141.08, 141.99, 142.38, 142.59, 141.42, 144.46, 144.96, 143.22, 
>   144.99, 145.86, 147.14, 149.03, 156.37, 159.78, 158.87, 160.08, 
>   164.93, 163.5, 160.28, 162.47, 159.52, 159.08, 156.9, 158.64, 
>   157.47, 155.13, 162.38, 164.7, 163.44, 161.25, 162.66, 159.24, 
>   155.15, 153.13, 152.31, 149.77, 151.31, 151.74, 150.9, 152.75, 
>   152.51, 157.56, 154.67, 155.25, 156.25, 156.85, 154.08, 159.32, 
>   154.99, 152.07, 152.41, 151.27, 151.58, 151.38, 151.35, 148.63, 
>   150.95, 148.45, 147.47, 147.53, 144.24, 145.79, 144.48, 142.95, 
>   147.41, 150.51, 151.46, 150.76, 147.88, 150.2, 150.74, 152.66, 
>   147.45, 151.57, 153.5, 150.9, 152.33, 155.53, 155.18, 153.59, 
>   152.59, 156.42, 162.12, 159.71, 163.75, 164.14, 161.67, 157.65, 
>   158.64, 156.64, 163.03, 163.89, 164.04, 165.96, 164.55, 165.58, 
>   171.21, 169.86, 172.53, 175.99, 178.2, 173.88, 173.03)), .Names = c("ticker", 
>   "date", "PX_LAST"), row.names = 200:400, class = "data.frame")

I hope that reproducible example is OK to replicate the issue I am running into. It seems like it shouldn't be such a difficult thing to reshape this data into a more conventional data frame: my goal is to have dates as rows and tickers as columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the package `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
FI_data %>% spread(ticker, PX_LAST)
```